# Android 8 : background services limit

Tags: android, service

When I test Service with app widget by Android 8:

I use remoteservice to get http request every 12 seconds.
And I found it can update always in background.
BUT I refer developer : https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#services
app widget is not in whitelist, I don't know why the service is always alive?

Comment: sorry it RemoteViewService

Comment: How do you check this? Is your test device charging? Android is less strict about services while charging.

Comment: No, I test with emulator

Comment: So go to settings and change it's charging state to 'discharging' so you can test properly.

Comment: After I try to discharging, it's still alive, anyway thanks for your reply

Comment: And also turn of the screen... :) You need the device to get into doze mode, It might take a few mins